# Setting up a LESS file watcher in PHPStorm 6 using node.js on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, less, phpstorm

I'm a recent convert to PHPStorm and absolutely loving it. I'm trying to get the 'File Watcher' to work with my LESS code, and I want it to use the lessc command. I have node.js installed and the command 'lessc' works from the windows command prompt, but it doesn't want to work within PHPStorm.

Here is my configuration for the file watcher:

[image]

When the file watcher runs, I get this error appear continuously:

> An exception occurred while executing watcher 'LESS'. Watcher is
>   disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc" (in directory
>   "F:\Plan2Share_v1\public\css"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a
>   valid Win32 application

As soon as I enable the watcher again, it somehow disables and throws me the above error again. I'm very new to node.js and PHPStorm. Any direction on where I might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Following @josh3736 's direction. I now get his error in the Run console of PHPStorm.

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc F:\Plan2Share_v1\public\css\style.less

C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc:2 basedir=`dirname "$0"`
        ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That error tells us that PHPStorm is calling [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), which can only start executables.   It cannot run scripts/batch files, which is what `lessc` is.  (PHPStorm would have to use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) for that.)

To work around this limitation, you'll have to specify the Node installation (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe most likely) as the executable, and the arguments should probably be something like `C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc $FileName$`

Comment: Following you direction I'm a few steps closer, I now just have the error in the edit above that I've just made.

Comment: On Windows you can just call **lessc.bat** file instead of `lessc` via node: `C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd` -- works just fine: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5481646#5481646

Answer (score 3):

1. Change Program: `C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd`
2. Change Arguments: `--no-color $FileName$`
3. Apply

Image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4287697/2014-09-26_11h25_29.png

Comment: Instead of just specifying C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc specify C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd and it works

Just a .cmd in front